# CoreData not saving information after being updated

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, save, edit

This function is supposed to add the current date into a list that is stored in memory whenever an addButton is pressed, however whenever the app is closed and reloaded the new date does not appear. The data also seems to disappear after switching views.

```
var selectedPersonFirst = ""
var selectedPersonLast = ""
let today = NSDate()



let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

@IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("People", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    let firstPred = NSPredicate(format: "(firstName = %@)", selectedPersonFirst)
    let secondPred = NSPredicate(format: "(lastName = %@)", selectedPersonLast)

    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [firstPred, secondPred])
    request.predicate = predicate

    var error: NSError?

    var objects = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)

    if let results = objects{

        let days = results[0].valueForKey("days") as! NSMutableArray
        days.addObject(NSDate())

        let person = results[0] as! People
        person.setValue(days, forKey: "days")

    }

    managedObjectContext!.save(nil)

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Here is the people subclass of NSManagedObject:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class People: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var days: AnyObject
    @NSManaged var dayZero: NSDate
    @NSManaged var firstName: String
    @NSManaged var gender: String
    @NSManaged var lastName: String

}
```

ViewController in which the `days` NSMutableArray is created:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class NewPersonViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var gender: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var dayZeroDate: UIDatePicker!

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    var personName : String = ""
    var currentDayNumber : Int? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        if segue.identifier == "DoneNewPersonSegue" {

            let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("People", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

            let person = People(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

            person.firstName = self.firstName.text
            person.lastName = self.lastName.text
            person.days = NSMutableArray()
            person.gender = gender.description
            person.dayZero = dayZeroDate.date

            save()

        }



    }

    func save() {
        var error : NSError?
        if(managedObjectContext!.save(&error) ) {
            println(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }


}
```

Data Model:

[image: Data Model]

Comment: How is `days` declared in your data model? And where do you create the initial `NSMutableArray` that you use for it?

Comment: @TomHarrington `days` is declared as an attribute of type `Transformable` in the entity `People`. The initial NSMutableArray is another view class, I will update the question to contain the code

Comment: Are you sure that objects is not nil (i.e. the fetch hasn't thrown an error)?  Also, if it is not nil, might it contain several objects?  I notice that your predicate is using `.OrPredicateType`, I think you might want `.AndPredicateType`?

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks for catching the predicate problem, but the object still doesn't appear after reloading the app. Also, I checked and the object isn't nil before being saved

Comment: By `objects` I was referring to the array returned by the fetch.  If the fetch is giving an error for some reason, `objects` will be nil and everything in your `if let results = objects {` will be skipped.

Comment: Oh, the fetch isn't giving me an error, and if I print to debug area

Comment: And if you check the result/pass an error argument in this line: `managedObjectContext!.save(nil)`?

Comment: The function returns true

Comment: So no problem there then.  Sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a mutable type, so a change wasn't calling the setter method. I changed the code to create a copy of the object so the change would be recognized:

```
let days1 = results[0].valueForKey("days") as! NSMutableArray
let days = days1.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray 

days.addObject(NSDate())
let person = results[0] as! People

person.setValue(days, forKey: "days”)
```